# Package pgfplots Error: CRITICAL: shader=interp: got unsupported pdf shading type '0'

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

For the set of data [here](https://pastebin.com/LSnkV2Cx), the following code can't compile showing the error

> Package pgfplots Error: CRITICAL: shader=interp: got unsupported pdf
>   shading type '0'. This may corrupt your pdf!.

```
\documentclass[border= 5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[unbounded coords=jump, view={70}{40}]
    \addplot3 [surf,shader=interp] 
    table [x index={0}, y index={1}, col sep=tab] {mySurfaceData.txt};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So, what went wrong to cause this?

P.S. the original data without `NaN` is available [here](https://pastebin.com/jbyV7HPY), where I would like to skip plotting those points of `z=1`.

Comment: Something is probably wrong with your data file unequal rows or groups etc. **EDIT** Actually probably due to some cells are being NaN cannot be shaded.

Comment: @percusse Alright, after checking my data, [here](https://pastebin.com/jbyV7HPY) you can find the raw data without NaN where I would like to skip plotting those points of `z>=1`. Additionally, the same data is available [here](https://pastebin.com/LSnkV2Cx) while replacing the z values of the points to skip with `NaN`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main issue is that you have to leave one empty line per group in your data such as this

```
0   0   1
0   0.2 1
0   0.4 1
0   0.6 1
0   0.8 1
0   1   1
0   1.2 1
0   1.4 1
0   1.6 1
0   1.8 1
0   2   1
0   2.2 1
0   2.4 1
0   2.6 1
0   2.8 1
0   3   1
0   3.2 1
0   3.4 1
0   3.6 1
0   3.8 1
0   4   1
0   4.2 1
0   4.4 1
0   4.6 1
0   4.8 1
0   5   1
0   5.2 1
0   5.4 1
0   5.6 1
0   5.8 1
0   6   1

0.2 0   1
0.2 0.2 1
0.2 0.4 1
0.2 0.6 1
0.2 0.8 1
0.2 1   1
0.2 1.2 1
0.2 1.4 1
0.2 1.6 1
0.2 1.8 1
0.2 2   1
0.2 2.2 1
0.2 2.4 1
0.2 2.6 1
0.2 2.8 1
0.2 3   1
0.2 3.2 1
0.2 3.4 1
0.2 3.6 1
0.2 3.8 1
0.2 4   1
0.2 4.2 1
0.2 4.4 1
0.2 4.6 1
0.2 4.8 1
0.2 5   1
0.2 5.2 1
0.2 5.4 1
0.2 5.6 1
0.2 5.8 1
0.2 6   1

0.4 0   1
0.4 0.2 1
0.4 0.4 1
0.4 0.6 1
0.4 0.8 1
0.4 1   1
0.4 1.2 1
0.4 1.4 1
0.4 1.6 1
0.4 1.8 1
0.4 2   1
0.4 2.2 1
0.4 2.4 1
0.4 2.6 1
0.4 2.8 1
0.4 3   1
0.4 3.2 1
0.4 3.4 1
0.4 3.6 1
0.4 3.8 1
0.4 4   1
0.4 4.2 1
0.4 4.4 1
0.4 4.6 1
0.4 4.8 1
0.4 5   1
0.4 5.2 1
0.4 5.4 1
0.4 5.6 1
0.4 5.8 1
0.4 6   1

0.6 0   1
0.6 0.2 1
0.6 0.4 1
0.6 0.6 1
0.6 0.8 1
0.6 1   1
0.6 1.2 1
0.6 1.4 1
0.6 1.6 1
0.6 1.8 1
0.6 2   1
0.6 2.2 1
0.6 2.4 1
0.6 2.6 1
0.6 2.8 1
0.6 3   1
0.6 3.2 1
0.6 3.4 1
0.6 3.6 1
0.6 3.8 1
0.6 4   1
0.6 4.2 1
0.6 4.4 1
0.6 4.6 1
0.6 4.8 1
0.6 5   1
0.6 5.2 1
0.6 5.4 1
0.6 5.6 1
0.6 5.8 1
0.6 6   1

0.8 0   1
0.8 0.2 1
0.8 0.4 1
0.8 0.6 1
0.8 0.8 1
0.8 1   1
0.8 1.2 1
0.8 1.4 1
0.8 1.6 1
0.8 1.8 1
0.8 2   1
0.8 2.2 1
0.8 2.4 1
0.8 2.6 1
0.8 2.8 1
0.8 3   1
0.8 3.2 1
0.8 3.4 1
0.8 3.6 1
0.8 3.8 1
0.8 4   1
0.8 4.2 1
0.8 4.4 1
0.8 4.6 1
0.8 4.8 1
0.8 5   1
0.8 5.2 1
0.8 5.4 1
0.8 5.6 1
0.8 5.8 1
0.8 6   1

1   0   0.29788
1   0.2 0.30895
1   0.4 0.35928
1   0.6 0.39989
1   0.8 0.47275
1   1   0.54074
1   1.2 0.61324
1   1.4 0.68626
1   1.6 0.76031
1   1.8 0.83381
1   2   0.9063
1   2.2 0.97466
1   2.4 1
1   2.6 1
1   2.8 1
1   3   1
1   3.2 1
1   3.4 1
1   3.6 1
1   3.8 1
1   4   1
1   4.2 1
1   4.4 1
1   4.6 1
1   4.8 1
1   5   1
1   5.2 1
1   5.4 1
1   5.6 1
1   5.8 1
1   6   1

1.2 0   0.27341
1.2 0.2 0.28421
1.2 0.4 0.31272
1.2 0.6 0.34844
1.2 0.8 0.39602
1.2 1   0.44535
1.2 1.2 0.49852
1.2 1.4 0.55192
1.2 1.6 0.6059
1.2 1.8 0.65859
1.2 2   0.70699
1.2 2.2 0.74459
1.2 2.4 0.73362
1.2 2.6 0.69729
1.2 2.8 0.67237
1.2 3   0.65348
1.2 3.2 0.63706
1.2 3.4 0.62313
1.2 3.6 0.61008
1.2 3.8 0.59822
1.2 4   0.58657
1.2 4.2 0.57648
1.2 4.4 0.56575
1.2 4.6 0.55533
1.2 4.8 0.54409
1.2 5   0.53197
1.2 5.2 0.51934
1.2 5.4 0.50581
1.2 5.6 0.49314
1.2 5.8 0.48142
1.2 6   0.47648

1.4 0   0.22609
1.4 0.2 0.24507
1.4 0.4 0.2699
1.4 0.6 0.29933
1.4 0.8 0.33498
1.4 1   0.37259
1.4 1.2 0.41242
1.4 1.4 0.45264
1.4 1.6 0.49292
1.4 1.8 0.53174
1.4 2   0.5669
1.4 2.2 0.59357
1.4 2.4 0.60377
1.4 2.6 0.59853
1.4 2.8 0.58862
1.4 3   0.57911
1.4 3.2 0.57091
1.4 3.4 0.5633
1.4 3.6 0.55599
1.4 3.8 0.549
1.4 4   0.54192
1.4 4.2 0.53496
1.4 4.4 0.5274
1.4 4.6 0.51927
1.4 4.8 0.5101
1.4 5   0.49983
1.4 5.2 0.48858
1.4 5.4 0.47657
1.4 5.6 0.46494
1.4 5.8 0.45504
1.4 6   0.4531

1.6 0   0.18784
1.6 0.2 0.20785
1.6 0.4 0.23097
1.6 0.6 0.2565
1.6 0.8 0.2851
1.6 1   0.31477
1.6 1.2 0.34563
1.6 1.4 0.37656
1.6 1.6 0.4073
1.6 1.8 0.43682
1.6 2   0.46384
1.6 2.2 0.48594
1.6 2.4 0.50064
1.6 2.6 0.50704
1.6 2.8 0.5097
1.6 3   0.51008
1.6 3.2 0.50927
1.6 3.4 0.50789
1.6 3.6 0.50601
1.6 3.8 0.5037
1.6 4   0.50079
1.6 4.2 0.49728
1.6 4.4 0.49278
1.6 4.6 0.48718
1.6 4.8 0.48016
1.6 5   0.4716
1.6 5.2 0.46157
1.6 5.4 0.45029
1.6 5.6 0.43852
1.6 5.8 0.42723
1.6 6   0.4175

1.8 0   0.15269
1.8 0.2 0.17483
1.8 0.4 0.19767
1.8 0.6 0.22088
1.8 0.8 0.24519
1.8 1   0.26963
1.8 1.2 0.29434
1.8 1.4 0.31875
1.8 1.6 0.34282
1.8 1.8 0.36603
1.8 2   0.38783
1.8 2.2 0.40719
1.8 2.4 0.42333
1.8 2.6 0.43598
1.8 2.8 0.44503
1.8 3   0.45159
1.8 3.2 0.45654
1.8 3.4 0.46027
1.8 3.6 0.463
1.8 3.8 0.46479
1.8 4   0.46558
1.8 4.2 0.46526
1.8 4.4 0.46363
1.8 4.6 0.46044
1.8 4.8 0.45542
1.8 5   0.44839
1.8 5.2 0.43927
1.8 5.4 0.42821
1.8 5.6 0.41556
1.8 5.8 0.40195
1.8 6   0.38749

2   0   0.12467
2   0.2 0.14823
2   0.4 0.17143
2   0.6 0.19242
2   0.8 0.21449
2   1   0.23524
2   1.2 0.2557
2   1.4 0.27544
2   1.6 0.29479
2   1.8 0.31362
2   2   0.33205
2   2.2 0.34976
2   2.4 0.36639
2   2.6 0.38143
2   2.8 0.39438
2   3   0.40525
2   3.2 0.41445
2   3.4 0.42221
2   3.6 0.42863
2   3.8 0.4338
2   4   0.43767
2   4.2 0.44018
2   4.4 0.44105
2   4.6 0.44007
2   4.8 0.43687
2   5   0.43117
2   5.2 0.42277
2   5.4 0.41163
2   5.6 0.39782
2   5.8 0.38181
2   6   0.36345
```

Then pgfplots understands the mesh properties otherwise it takes it as a one big patch. After that you can use anything you want. Here is an example

```
\documentclass[border= 5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[unbounded coords=jump, view={70}{40},colormap/viridis]
    \addplot3 [surf,shader=faceted] table {mySurfaceData.txt};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would really suggest not using tab separated documents as they usually get lost in the file encodings and also annoying for different editors.

[image]

If you want to skip certain levels add `restrict z to domain=0:0.999` but then you will loose the patch corners and number of patches will be decreased. There is no way to cut patches into parts either on or off.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but is it not possible to follow the same approach of [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410997/2288) to my previous question where I was able to produce a conditional plot?

Comment: @Diaa You can. But you need to have the empty lines

Comment: @percusse, can you please explain or point to a place where the need to empty lines is explained? I'd appreciate it!